# Broken Pipe error when starting Spring-boot/JPA app - Immediate test query succeeds

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

The maven project was constructed using start.spring.io a couple of days ago. I tried testing this to H2 and everything was fine.  I then switched to an existing Oracle DB with schema already defined (see below for table definition in oracle);

The log output when starting my spring-boot app using jpa to oracle is as follows:

```
 50 2020-08-31 15:32:45.763 DEBUG 60586 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : Adding type registration imm_serializable -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@939e    8a8
 49 2020-08-31 15:32:45.790  INFO 60586 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
 48 2020-08-31 15:32:45.827  WARN 60586 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection   : HikariPool-1 - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@5f5a9b2b marked as broken beca    use of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)
 47 
 46 java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Broken pipe
 45         at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:779) ~[ojdbc8-19.7.0.0.jar:19.7.0.0.0]
 44         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:983) ~[ojdbc8-19.7.0.0.jar:19.7.0.0.0]
 43         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168) ~[ojdbc8-19.7.0.0.jar:19.7.0.0.0]
 42         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1362) ~[ojdbc8-19.7.0.0.jar:19.7.0.0.0]
 41         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:369) ~[ojdbc8-19.7.0.0.jar:19.7.0.0.0]
 40         at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getTypeInfo(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:901) ~[ojdbc8-19.7.0.0.jar:19.7.0.0.0]
 39         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyDatabaseMetaData.getTypeInfo(ProxyDatabaseMetaData.java:199) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
 38         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyDatabaseMetaData.getTypeInfo(HikariProxyDatabaseMetaData.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
 37         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.TypeInfo.extractTypeInfo(TypeInfo.java:84) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
 36         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.ExtractedDatabaseMetaDataImpl$Builder.apply(ExtractedDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
 35         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
 34         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.20.Final.jar:5.4.20.Final]
```

Oracle table definition:

```
  CREATE TABLE "STATEDB"."ASR_RUN" 
   (    "RUN_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "RUN_TEXT_ID" VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "RUN_STATUS" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "WORKSPACE_NAME" VARCHAR2(80), 
    "PROJECT_NAME" VARCHAR2(80), 
    "WORKING_DIRECTORY" VARCHAR2(1024), 
    "RUN_START_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
    "RUN_STOP_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH TIME ZONE, 
    "ELAPSED_TIME" NUMBER, 
    "DELETED" CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N', 
     UNIQUE ("RUN_TEXT_ID")
```

My application.properties file:

```
18 # Turn Statistics on
 17 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=tru
 16 logging.level.org.hibernate.stat=debug
 15 
 14 # Show all queries
 13 spring.jpa.show-sql=true
 12 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=sql
 11 logging.level.org.hibernate.type=debug
 10 
  9 # Set h2 to static port and url
  8 #spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
  7 #spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap.mode=default
  6 
  5 #Basic Spring Boot Config for Oracle
  4 spring.datasource.url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.30.0.44:1521/ORCL12
  3 spring.datasource.username=********
  2 spring.datasource.password=*******
  1 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  0 
  1 #hibernate config
  2 spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
  3 
  4 spring.datasource.hikari.connection_timeout=5000
  5 spring.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
  6
```

My pom.xml dependencies:

```
               <dependency>
 50                         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 49                         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
 48                 </dependency>
 47                 <dependency>
 46                         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 45                         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
 44                 </dependency>
 43                 <dependency>
 42                         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 41                         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
 40                 </dependency>
 39                 <dependency>
 38                         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 37                         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
 36                 </dependency>
 35                 <dependency>
 34                         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 33                         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
 32                 </dependency>
 31                 <dependency>
 30                         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 29                         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
 28                 </dependency>
 27 
 26                 <dependency>
 25                         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 24                         <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
 23                         <scope>runtime</scope>
 22                         <optional>true</optional>
 21                 </dependency>
 20                 <dependency>
 19                         <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
 18                         <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
 17                         <scope>runtime</scope>
 16                 </dependency>
 15                 <dependency>
 14                         <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
 13                         <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
 12                         <optional>true</optional>
 11                 </dependency>
 10                 <dependency>
  9                         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  8                         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  7                         <scope>test</scope>
  6                 </dependency>
  5                 <dependency>
  4                         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  3                         <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
  2                         <scope>test</scope>
  1                 </dependency>
```

The definition of my enity:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
  1 import javax.persistence.Column;
  2 import javax.persistence.Entity;
 ⚠  import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 ⚠  import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
  5 import javax.persistence.Id;
  6 import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
 ⚠  import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
  8 import javax.persistence.Table;
  9 import lombok.Data;
 10 
 11 
 12 @NamedQuery(name="get_all_runs", query="select r from ASRRun r")
 13 @Entity
 14 @Table(name="ASR_RUN")  
 15 @Data
 16 public class ASRRun {
 17         @Id     
 18         @Column(name="RUN_ID")
 19         long runId;     
 20         @Column(name="RUN_TEXT_ID")
 21         String runTextid;
 22         @Column(name="RUN_STATUS")
 23         String runStatus;
 24         @Column(name="WORKSPACE_NAME")
 25         String workspaceName;
 26         @Column(name="PROJECT_NAME")
 27         String projectName;
 28         @Column(name="WORKING_DIRECTORY")
 29         String workingDirectory;
 30 
 31         @Column(name="RUN_START_TIME")
 32         Timestamp runStartTime;
 33         @Column(name="RUN_STOP_TIME")
 34         Timestamp runStopTime;
 35         @Column(name="ELAPSED_TIME")
 36         long elapsedTime;
 37         @Column(name="DELETED")
 38         char deleted;
 39 
 40 
 41         @Override
 42         public String toString(){
 43                 return runId + " = " + workspaceName + ":" + projectName + " - START:" + runStartTime + " - STOP:" + runStopTime;
 44         }
 45 
 46 
 47 }
```

I'm also seeing this a couple dozen lines down from the original error:

```
 2020-08-31 15:32:45.828  WARN 60586 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.TypeInfo   : HHH000362: Unable to retrieve type info result set : java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO     Error: Broken pipe
  8 2020-08-31 15:32:45.831 ERROR 60586 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.j.e.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl   : Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
  7 
  6 java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
  5         at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:515) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
  4         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.createStatement(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

The strange thing is that a test query to my repository class (ASRRunRepository) is returning results.

Does anyone know what this could be caused by and how to resolve it?  Your help would be much appreciated!